# solving maze in python

Tags: python, recursion

I found this code to solve a maze like this:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |         |   |   |
S +-+-+-+-+ + +-+ + +
|         | |     | |
+-+-+-+ +-+ +-+-+-+ +
|     | |   |       |
+ + + + + +-+ +-+-+-+
| | | | |       |   |
+ + +-+ +-+-+ + + + +
| |   | |   | |   | |
+ +-+ + + + + +-+-+-+
| |   |   | |       |
+ + +-+-+-+ + +-+-+ +
| |         | |     |
+ +-+-+ +-+-+ +-+-+-+
| |   |     |   |   |
+ + + +-+-+-+-+ + +-+
| | | | |       |   |
+ + + + + + +-+-+-+ +
|   |     |         E
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

this is the code:

```
def read_maze(fname):
    mz = []
    with open(fname, 'U') as f:
        for r in f:
            mz.append(list(r.replace('\n', '')))
    return mz



PATH, START, EXIT, VISITED, SOLUTION = " SE.o"


class Maze():
    def __init__(self,maze):
        self.maze = maze
        self.start_y = [row.count(START) for row in self.maze].index(1)
        self.start_x = self.maze[self.start_y].index(START)
    def __repr__(self):
        return  "\n".join("".join(row)for row in self.maze)
    def solve(self, x=None, y=None):
        if x==None:
            x, y = self.start_x,self.start_y
        if self.maze[y][x] in (PATH,START):
            self.maze[y][x] = VISITED
            if self.solve(x+1,y) or self.solve(x-1,y) or self.solve(x,y+1) or self.solve(x,y-1):
                self.maze[y][x]=SOLUTION
                return True
        elif self.maze[y][x] == EXIT:
            return True
        return False

maze = read_maze("maze.txt")


mz = Maze(maze)
print (mz)
print ("-----------------------------")
if mz.solve():
    print(mz)
```

can anyone help me to understand the recursive function `solve()`?

First of all, the function check if the current position is in PATH or START, it will be obviously in START for the first time, that in our case is (x=0;y=2). So the code mark it as VISITED.

What I dont completely understand is what the program do next? There is an if condition and the first option to check is `self.solve(x+1,y)` - in this case we are going to right, that is a free position and it is in PATH (so we mark it as VISITED), but (x+1+1,y) is not, so we pass to the second value of our `or` (that is `(x-1,y)` so we obtain again `(x+1+(1-1),y) = (x+1,y)`, now we pass to the third `(x,y+1)` so we go down etc.

Is it correct? i'm lost a bit.

Comment: Assuming you wrote this code, why don't you understand it?

Comment: @cricket_007, they didn't: they say they've _found_ that code somewhere right at the beginning of the post.

Comment: i wrote "i've found the code", i need a fully comprehension of it

Comment: It's a bad practice to copy (and especially run) code you don't fully understand

Comment: Draw your map on paper, then run the algorithm line by line using pencil

Comment: I'm studying it because seems to me a simple example of how recursive function works, i understand the most part of it, but i need to get the most important part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inline Explanation**

```
def solve(self, x=None, y=None):

    # initializes x, y as start location
    # occurs during first call of 'solve', i.e. zeroth recursion
    if x==None: 
        x, y = self.start_x,self.start_y

    # equivalent to, if the current (x, y) tile is walk-able
    # implicitly ignores visited tiles
    if self.maze[y][x] in (PATH,START):

        # mark tile (x, y) as visited
        self.maze[y][x] = VISITED

        # if one of the adjacent tiles from (x, y) leads to a solution
        # this is where the recursion occurs, i.e. 'solve' is called using the adjacent tiles
        # this will be recursively called until one of the calls return True upon finding the exit
        # when one of the calls encounter an exit, then this will create a chain reaction where each call returns True to its caller until the first call returns true
        if self.solve(x+1,y) or self.solve(x-1,y) or self.solve(x,y+1) or self.solve(x,y-1):

            # mark (x, y) as part of the solution
            self.maze[y][x]=SOLUTION

            # tells that a solution has been found, value used by caller
            return True

    # if the (x, y) tile is the exit then a solution has been found
    elif self.maze[y][x] == EXIT:
        return True

    # if non of the if statements return, then by default no solution has been found where tile (x, y) is in the solution path.
    return False
```

**Maze legends**

- `<space>` walk-able tile
- `S` start tile
- `E` exit tile
- `.` visited tile
- `o` tile that is part of the solution path
- all other tiles are non walk-able tiles

**Maze before `solve()`**

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |         |   |   |
S +-+-+-+-+ + +-+ + +
|         | |     | |
+-+-+-+ +-+ +-+-+-+ +
|     | |   |       |
+ + + + + +-+ +-+-+-+
| | | | |       |   |
+ + +-+ +-+-+ + + + +
| |   | |   | |   | |
+ +-+ + + + + +-+-+-+
| |   |   | |       |
+ + +-+-+-+ + +-+-+ +
| |         | |     |
+ +-+-+ +-+-+ +-+-+-+
| |   |     |   |   |
+ + + +-+-+-+-+ + +-+
| | | | |       |   |
+ + + + + + +-+-+-+ +
|   |     |         E
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

**Maze after `solve()`**

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |.........|...|...|
oo+-+-+-+-+.+.+-+.+.+
|ooooooo..|.|.....|.|
+-+-+-+o+-+.+-+-+-+.+
|ooo..|o|...|.......|
+o+o+.+o+.+-+.+-+-+-+
|o|o|.|o|.......|...|
+o+o+-+o+-+-+.+.+.+.+
|o|ooo|o|ooo|.|...|.|
+o+-+o+o+o+o+.+-+-+-+
|o|ooo|ooo|o|.......|
+o+o+-+-+-+o+.+-+-+.+
|o|ooooooooo|.|.....|
+o+-+-+ +-+-+.+-+-+-+
|o|ooo|     |...|   |
+o+o+o+-+-+-+-+.+ +-+
|o|o|o| |ooo....|   |
+o+o+o+ +o+o+-+-+-+ +
|ooo|ooooo|oooooooooE
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Answer (score 1):

`solve` returns `True` only if the code is on the Exit tile or part of the path that leads to the Exit tile. Now the code dives into the maze recursively: every time a 'PATH' tile is found, it marks it as `VISITED` and visits all neighbouring tiles (next recursion) or a wall tile upon which it returns 'False' (can't continue this direction). This goes on until the `EXIT` tile is finally found, which returns the first 'True'. This decreases recursion by one and changes the `VISITED` flag to `SOLUTION`, returns `True` again, decreasing recursion again. This now goes on until the code is back on the `START` tile.

Hope this helps.